# Splitting multipatch based on whether features are connected

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, multipart, multipatch

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2.

I have an OBJ file of several hundred buildings that, when imported using the Import 3D Files tool, is converted to a multipatch file with a single multipart feature for all buildings. My objective is to split the single feature into individual multipatch features, one for each building. I have tried two approaches:

- Explode the multipatch feature using the editing tool 'Explode'. This breaks the file into a single feature for each *building face*, which is too broken out for my needs. I tried using the 'Merge' editing tool to group all faces of a building into a single feature, but this would not work properly - the merge would run successfully but the faces were still separate features.
- Run the Multipart to Singlepart tool on the multipatch file. The tool would run successfully, but the results included many triangle features for each building, again far too broken up for my needs.

Is there a different approach to split the multipatch based solely on whether the features are geographically connected?